# Querying ISODate from mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, nodes

I am trying to query ISODate from mongodb, but for some reason the day of the month is always off by one day.

For Example:

In MongoDb

```
 "lastDate" : ISODate("2016-12-10T00:00:00.000+0000")
```

when i query using nodejs i get

```
Fri Dec 09 2016 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

as you can see it returnes the Date with one day off

is it something to do with the time zone, any suggestions how to fix this

Comment: It's just in your local time zone and I'm pretty sure that's how you would like it be displayed. The mongodb has its in UTC time and that's your offset.

Comment: should i increment the day @SagarReddy

Comment: No that is the correct time in your local zone. Why do you want to change it ?

Comment: because the date in the database is 2016-12-10 but it returns 2016-12-09 @SagarReddy

Comment: The date in database not specific to any timezone. That is how Mongo db saves it. Its just an instant in time. So for that time to make any sense you have to convert that to your time zone. So EST is -05:00 behind UTC time. So your date changes to 2016-12-09 07:00(EST) which is -05:00 from 2016-12-10 00:00(UTC). You dont have to do any further changes and there is nothing to fix here. Read a little bit on time zone and it all will make sense.